# Matlab: Use time series results from one for-loop as input into a second for-loop.?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, time-series

How do you use the time series results (As) from one for-loop as input into a second for loop? Can you have 2 for-loops in one .m file?  Or do I separate them into two .m files.  If I separate them, how do you get call the first function's output in the second loop's equations?

```
x=load('C:....dat'); %Load the file with data of precipitation, temperature and snowpack
td=x(:,4);              %hour of the day
GlobalRad=x(:,5);          %Global Radiation
T=x(:,6);                %Air Temperature
P=x(:,7);                %Precipitation
Snow_obs=x(:,8);           %SWE Observed
SnowDepth=x(:,9);        %Snow Depth Observed
ts=x(:,10);                %start time of daylight on day d (t0)
te=x(:,11);               %end time of daylight on day d (t1)
dTd=x(:,12);              %difference between the max and min daily temperatures on day d

snow_sim(1)=0;
runoff=zeros(length(P));

%Parameters
Scf=1.3;                        %Snowfall correction factor
TT=1;                          %Threshold temperature
C=3.5;                           %Degree-day factor (mm day-1 C-1)(Ac)
Cfr=0.05;                        %Refreezing coefficient (use default value of 0.05)
Cwh=0.1;                         %Water holding capacity (use default value of 0.1)
B=0.05;         % Factor to convert the temp amplitude into a degree day factor


snow_sim(1)=0;                   %Simulated snowpack is 0 mm for day 1
snow_sim_water(1)=0;             %Liquid water in snowpack for day 1 the water is 0 mm


for t=1 : length(td);       %**FIRST time series loop**

    ln(t)=24-te(t)+ts(t);                    %length of the night
    Z(t)=2*((te(t)-ts(t))/(3.14*ln(t)));        %factor ensuring that daily mean vaules of As equals Ac

    if ts(t)<=td(t)<te(t);

      As(t)=C+(B*dTd(t)*(sin(3.14*((td(t)-ts(t))/(te(t)-ts(t))))));       %equation for time variant degree day factor secnario1

    else As(t)=C-(B*dTd(t)*Z(t));            %equation for time variant degree day factor senario 2

    end
end


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



for t=2 : length(P);             %**SECOND time series loop**

    if T(t)< TT;                 %If the temperature for day t is lower than the threshold value for melting (=below TT degrees) then refreezing of melt water will occur
        refreez(t)=Cfr*As*(TT-T(t));      %Equation for refreezing of meltwater
        if refreez(t) > snow_sim_water(t-1);     %If the refreezing for day t is larger than the water in the snowpack the day before, then the refreezing is limited
            refreez(t)= snow_sim_water(t-1);      %Can't freez more water than is accumulated in the snowpack
        end

        snow_sim(t)=P(t)*Scf+snow_sim(t-1)+refreez(t);     %The total simulated snowpack for any given day is the precipitation that day together with snow pack from day before and refreeze of that day.
        snow_sim_water(t)=snow_sim_water(t-1)-refreez(t);        %The total simulated amount of water in the snowpack is the water in the snowpack the day before minus the water refrozen the same day


    else %T(t) > TT                   %temperature above threshold temperature, snowmelt will occur
        Melt(t)=As*(T(t)-TT);           %Equations for melting rate of existing snowpack
        if Melt(t) > snow_sim(t-1);    %If the melting rate for day t is larger than the snowpack the day before, then the melting is limited
            Melt(t)= snow_sim(t-1);     %Because it can't melt more snow than is available
        end
        snow_sim(t)=snow_sim(t-1)-Melt(t);                  %Total simulated snow is the simulated snowpack for the day before minus the melted snow
        snow_sim_water(t)=snow_sim_water(t-1)+P(t)+Melt(t);       %Total water amount in snow is the water amount in snow for the day before plus the precipitation and the melted snow
        if Cwh*snow_sim(t) < snow_sim_water(t);                 %The snowpack can retain as much as 10% of its water equivalent, but not more
            runoff(t)=snow_sim_water(t)-0.1*snow_sim(t);        %if there is more liquid water, this goes to runoff (note:if there is no snowpack all water will go to runoff
            snow_sim_water(t)=0.1*snow_sim(t);
        end
    end
end



snow_sim_total=snow_sim+snow_sim_water;                   %The total simulated snowpack is the water in snow and the simulated snowpack

daynr=1:length(P);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many for-loops in a script or function as you like. Avoid them where you can and vectorize your code instead

e.g.:

```
As=zeros(size(te));
diff1=te-ts; % this difference gets used multiple times
ln=24-diff1;
Z=2*diff1./(pi*ln);
ix=ts<=td<te;
As(ix)=C+(B*dTd(ix).*sin(pi*((td(ix)-ts(ix))./diff1(ix))));
As(~ix)=C-(B*dTd(~ix).*Z(~ix));
```

does the same as the first for loop, but will run considerably faster.

It appears that As is a vector, yet in your second loop, you treat it as a scalar, seems like you are missing the time index there ( i.e.

```
refreez(t)=Cfr*As*(TT-T(t));
```

should be

```
refreez(t)=Cfr*As(t)*(TT-T(t));
```

I think.

This loop is probably not easy to vectorize, since computations within it depend on previous results, so could leave it as it is and just fix the errors.
You should have no trouble running both loops in the same script, once you fixed the errors in the second loop.

Comment: Thank you Felix!  I appreciate the help!!